# Code for Hypergeometric function

Tags: numerical-methods, special-functions

I am searching  for Fortran code for hypergeometric functions $_pF_q$ with real arguments. Looking forward for your suggestions in this regard.

Comment: the hypergeometric functions in it standard form are very bad to implement directly in software because the error for approximations is so big. Try to search for papers for series, or algorithms, that represent hypergeometric functions that converges very fast or where the error is controlled.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [NUMERICAL RECIPES IN FORTRAN 77](https://www.amazon.ca/Numerical-Recipes-FORTRAN-Scientific-Computing/dp/052143064X). Look in the special functions chapter.

Also, you can look at [the Special Functions library](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/special_functions/special_functions.html), which has an implementation of it I think.

Comment: Both the libraries contain code for Gauss's series. I need {}_3F_2, {}_2F_1.

Comment: Hmm, maybe in the [CPC](http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/subjectIndex/SUBJECT_4.html)? Looking for the original source of [this matlab package](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5616-generalized-hypergeometric-function) might help too (or translating it yourself). In particular, see [this cpc lib, ACPA_v1_0](http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/summaries/ACPA_v1_0.html) for the generalized hypergeometric.

Comment: @Purnendu This is just to ping you... for some reason I can't edit my comment...

Comment: Will try cpc and let you know.  Thank you for the reference.