# Solve the numerical value of this integral $\int_0^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t} \Gamma(b,t)dt$

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods

I need to compute the numerical value of this integral, hundred thousand of times, for a typical dataset. How can I get a good approximation.

$$
 \int_0^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t} \Gamma(b,t)dt
$$
where a and b are positive integer and $\Gamma(b,t)=\int_t^\infty \lambda^{b-1}e^{-\lambda}d\lambda$

Comment: You should check your expression of the [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function). According to Mathematica the first integral has a closed form involving the Gamma and Hypergeometric functions. There are numerical libraries to compute this (Gamma is integrated is most languages, and see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303343/code-for-hypergeometric-function) for the hypergeometric).

Comment: More specifically, the first integral is $$\dfrac{1}{a}\Gamma(a+b)_2F_1(a,a+b;1+a;-1)$$

Comment: @Jean that solved my problem!

Comment: @Jean I corrected the incomplete Gamma function

Comment: Mathematica returns the following result: $\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{a} _2F_1(a, a+b; a+1; -1)$, provided $\mathrm{Re}(a)>0$ and $\mathrm{Re}(a+b)>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Heres how I tried to derive a solution for your integral, of course more rigor could be applied to say why the steps are valid but I think this is sufficient

[image]